# Dynamic variable in JSON showed in PHP

Tags: php, json

I've tried to look up the clue, still not able to solve it though.

I have json like this, and I need it to store in db the following 'id', 'n', 'ct'. But the element "rep" has various numbering. Can anyone help me to create the code "foreach" to be able to call it and then save it? 
Basically I need to get result for each "rep" with its "id"

Such as:

> rep1 - id 1,2,4,5
>
> rep2 - id 1,2

```
{       "dataFlags": 8192,
        "totalItemsCount": 6,
        "indexFrom": 0,
        "indexTo": 0,
        "items": [{
                "rep": {
                    "1": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "n": "volvo",
                        "ct": "avl_unit_group",
                        "c": 54071
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "n": "bmw",
                        "ct": "avl_unit_group",
                        "c": 59631
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "n": "audi",
                        "ct": "avl_unit_group",
                        "c": 27264
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "n": "mercedes",
                        "ct": "avl_unit",
                        "c": 18276
            }}},
            {"rep": {
                    "1": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "n": "tesla",
                        "ct": "avl_unit",
                        "c": 24132
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "n": "scania",    
                        "ct": "avl_unit",
                        "c": 2178
                    }},
                "repmax": 0
}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is written in php.

```
         $rep1="";  
        foreach ($row['item'] as $key => $value) {
            $rep1 .=$value->id.'-';
        }
        $rep1=substr($rep1, 0, -1);
```

the output will be  $rep1= 1-2-4-5

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data:

```
 $jsonData = '{ 
        "dataFlags": 8192,
        "totalItemsCount": 6,
        "indexFrom": 0,
        "indexTo": 0,
        "items": [{
                "rep": {
                    "1": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "n": "volvo",
                        "ct": "avl_unit_group",
                        "c": 54071
                    },......
                }},
            {"rep": {
                    "1": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "n": "tesla",
                        "ct": "avl_unit",
                        "c": 24132
                    },..........
                    },
                "repmax": 0
}]}';
```

Try below code. it's working. I have used 2 `foreach`  for store your JSON data in the database.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonData,true);
foreach($jsonData['items'] as $items){      
     foreach($items['rep'] as $rep){          
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (id, n, ct) VALUES   (".$rep['id'].",".$rep['n'].",".$rep['ct'].")";
        $conn->query($sql)        
     }        
}
```

Get result for each "rep" with its "id":

```
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonData,true);
$allRep = [];
foreach($jsonData['items'] as $items){
    $tmpRep = [];
    foreach($items['rep'] as $key => $rep){          
        $tmpRep [] = $key;
    }
    $allRep[] = implode(', ',$tmpRep);

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($allRep);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1, 2, 4, 5
    [1] => 1, 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$arr = json_decode($yourJSONstring);

foreach($arr->items as $index=>$rep){
    foreach($rep->rep as $element){
        $reps[$index][] = $element->id;
    }
}
```

Reps array will look like:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
)
```

So you can easily convert it to string format as you desire.